# How to iterate counter in XSLT 1.0 based on some condition

Tags: templates, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where I have to increment the count and assign that value to one of the target element.

For ex - My input request is something like this

```
<Deliveries>
<Delivery>
<OrderNo>
1234
</OrderNo>
<orderItem>
12
</orderItem>
</Delivery>
<Delivery>
<OrderNo>
S1234
</OrderNo>
<orderItem>
12
</orderItem>
</Delivery>
</Deliveries>
```

Delivery is parent element which is unbounded and my output XSD is nothing but table columns.

```
<Order_table>
<Orders>
<column1>
<column2>
</Orders>
</Order_table>
```

Now My requirement is that If OrderNo contains first letter as S then I have to assign 1 value to column1 else I have to simply copy the value of orderItem. and every time I get the OrderNo value starting with S then I have to increment the value by 1 but if orderNo is not starting with S then it should not increase by 1. Due to this logic , I am not able to use position function  as well.

For example -

If my input is something like -

```
<Deliveries>
    <Delivery>
    <OrderNo>
     S1234
    </OrderNo>
    <orderItem>
    12
    </orderItem>
    </Delivery>
    <Delivery>
    <OrderNo>
    1234
    </OrderNo>
    <orderItem>
    12
    </orderItem>
    </Delivery>
<Delivery>
    <OrderNo>
    S1234
    </OrderNo>
    <orderItem>
    12
    </orderItem>
    </Delivery>

    </Deliveries>
```

Then my output should be -

```
<Order_table>
    <Orders>
    <column1>1</column1> <-- First value as 1 as Order starts from S  
 <column2>
    </Orders>
 <Orders>
    <column1>12</column1> copy of orderItem bcz orderNo don't start with S
    <column2>
    </Orders>

 <Orders>
    <column1>2</column1> Increment from 1 to 2 as Order again starts from S
    <column2>
    </Orders>

    </Order_table>
```

Could any please help  me with my issue ? A piece of code will help me a lot.

Comment: Which value do you want to increase, the `orderItem` value? Please fill the wanted result sample with data to allow us to see how input elements are mapped to output elements.

Comment: So, in short -- for column 1 you have to choose 1 when orderno starts-with "S", otherwise set it too the orderNo.   And then in addition to this you want to count of all deliveries with an orderNo that starts-with "S" and put the resut into some other place that you've not told us.     I dont see any need for position() and I may have given you some clues in my comment!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Order_table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//OrderNo"/>
    </Order_table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderNo[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'S')]">
    <Orders>
        <column1>
            <xsl:number level="any" count="OrderNo[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'S')]"/>
        </column1>
        <column2/>
    </Orders>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderNo">
    <Orders>
        <column1><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../orderItem)"/></column1>
        <column2/>
    </Orders>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hello, Please find entire logic again. If OrderNo NOT start with S then I have to simply copy the value of OrderItem to column which is not the problem. My problem is when it is equal to S then column1 should get value as 1 for the first time and if this scenario repeats then its value should get increase by 1 but if in between I get a record with orderNo NOT starting with S then counter should not increase. I hope this will clear your doubt

Comment: I appears thatn none of us are understanding your logic,  Can you edit the quuestion with an example of an input and output with values

Comment: Hello  Phill , 

I have updated my question with Example !! Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Now you have provided a more complete description of the problem, I have expanded my answer to give a complete stylesheet that delivers the required output (except that your specimen output isn't well-formed - the column2 elements are not closed).

Answer (score 0):

When your context is placed at a Delivery node, test for starts-with(OrderNo,'S'), then count backward the number of siblings using the same test.  This will give you your incrementing value.

```
<xsl:template match="Delivery">
    <Orders>

        <column1>

            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="starts-with(OrderNo,'S')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="1+count(preceding-sibling::Delivery[starts-with(OrderNo,'S')])"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="orderItem"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>

        </column1>

        <column2/>
    </Orders>
</xsl:template>
```

You will of course, also need complete the remainder of the stylesheet yourself, but this covers the logical that you outline in your question.

Comment: The xsl:number approach is more likely to be optimized by the XSLT processor, but of course it depends on the processor.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about xsl:number!  @KushalKaria - go for Michael Kay's answer. They both work but Michaels is a far more robust (and complete) solution.

Comment: Hello Michael,

Could you please give me a small piece of code with number function?

Comment: @KushalKaria - its already there!   Just scroll up the page a bit :-)

Comment: Hello Phill,

Sorry for troubling you again.

I am stil not able to find !

Comment: There are only two answers provided for the question.  In Michaels answer (with the positive rating) he is using the xsl:number in the middle template.